# I want to add watch video functionality in my flutter app

Tags: flutter, api, flutter-dependencies

I am using TMDB (The Movie Database) Api. I am stuck in watch video functionality. How can i add watch video functionality with suitable code?

Api response

[image]

My code

```
class upcoming_detail extends StatefulWidget {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 300,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    image: NetworkImage(
                      "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${widget.image}",
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned.fill(
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.play_circle_fill,
                      size: 70,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {

                      // handle video play action
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

If TMDB API provides a video link then you can use [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) package to your app. The package has clear docs you can check the example in it.
Hope this is usefully to you.

Comment: TMDB don't provide any video link

Comment: I saw "video" boolean key in the response image you have provided, so maybe there is another api to get the movie video link. but overall video_player package is the one for playing any kind of video in the app.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).